# Convergence of $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+n+1})^{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Find if the following series converge: $$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+n+1}\right)^{n^2}$$

What I did:

$$a_n=\left(\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+n+1}\right)^{n^2}$$

$$b_n=\frac {1}{(n+1)^{n^2}}$$

$$\forall n\ge 1 : a_n < b_n \ \Rightarrow \ \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+n+1}\right)^{n^2}<\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {1}{(n+1)^{n^2}} \approx \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {n^2}$$

> $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ converges like $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac 1 {n^2}$ so $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges as well.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the first inequality.  By itself, the term in the parenthesis approaches $1$ as $n \to \infty$; it does not vanish as you assert.

Comment: See also:
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/254853
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3031251
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2874602
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3515638

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely what I'd have a Calculus student do. Use the root test:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left| \left(\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+n+1}\right)^{n^2}\right|^\frac{1}{n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{n^2+1}{n^2+n+1}\right)^n$$

$$\begin{array} \\
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln \left(\left( \frac{n^2+1}{n^2+n+1}\right)^n\right) &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \ln \left( \frac{n^2+1}{n^2+n+1}\right) \\
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln \left( \frac{n^2+1}{n^2+n+1}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}} \\
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\left( \frac{n^2+n+1}{n^2+1}\right)\left(\frac{(n^2+n+1)(2n)-(n^2+1)(2n+1)}{(n^2+n+1)^2}\right)}{-\frac{1}{n^2}} \\
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} -\frac{n^2(2n^3+2n^2+2n - 2n^3 - n^2 - 2n - 1)}{(n^2+1)(n^2+n+1)} \\
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} -\frac{n^2(n^2-1)}{(n^2+1)(n^2+n+1)} = -1
\end{array}$$

Now since the limit of $\ln (f(n)) = -1$, we have that the limit of $f(n) = \frac{1}{e} < 1$, and the series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Can you please explain how you got that ? Is it LHR ?

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\left( \frac{n^2+n+1}{n^2+1}\right)\left(\frac{(n^2+n+1)(2n)-(n^2+1)(2n+1)}{(n^2+n+1)^2}\right)}{-\frac{1}{n^2}} \\
$$

Comment: Yes, L'Hopital's Rule. Chain Rule then Quotient Rule on top.

Comment: Good. It was easier to derive that by using: $\ln (x/y)=\ln x - \ln y$. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, good point. That would be a bit easier.

Answer (score 5):

I would take the following approach:

$$\begin{align}\left (\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+n+1}\right )^{n^2} &= \left (1-\frac{n}{n^2+n+1}\right )^{n^2}\\ &=e^{n^2 \log{\left (1-\frac{n}{n^2+n+1}\right )}} \\ &\sim e^{-n^2 (1/n - 1/(2 n^2))}\\ &\sim e^{-n+1/2} \end{align}$$

Thus the series converges by comparison with a geometric series.

Comment: That's a lot of approximations. Is my approach wrong ?

Comment: @GinKin: I see exactly two approximations, both very valid as $n \to \infty$.  As far as your approach goes, I do not understand it.  How do you get a comparison with $1/n^2$?

Comment: It should be $\sim e^{-n+1/2}$.  Gotta expand up to $o(1)$ inside an exponential to get $\sim$ outside :)

Comment: I didn't know that you can remove the log like that in approximation. I edited my answer a bit, it should be more clear now.

Comment: @AntonioVargas: good point, I sometimes glance over that fact in this sort of problem.  Doesn't change the answer to the question, but does keep us honest.  Thanks.