# Finding if the given series converges or not: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+n+1}\right)^{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to find if the following series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+n+1}\right)^{n^2}$$

converges or not.

I’ve tried root test so far, but reached 1 as the limit, which according to the related theorems, doesn’t yield any result.

Comment: What would you think about $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n^2}$?

Comment: Using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Bn%5E2%2B1%7D%7Bn%5E2%2Bn%2B1%7D%5Cright)%5E%7Bn%5E2%7D%24&p=1) or [SearchOnMath}(https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=$%7B%5Csum_%7Bn=1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Bn%5E2%2B1%7D%7Bn%5E2%2Bn%2B1%7D%5Cright)%5E%7Bn%5E2%7D%7D$), you could find several posts about the same series. See also: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Comment: Here are some posts about this series:
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/254853
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/748110
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3031251
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2874602

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cf. Henry's comment.

$$a_n=\left( 1-\dfrac{n}{n^2+n+1} \right) ^{n^2}$$

$$b_n:=n+1+1/n$$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n=\infty$$

$$a_n=\left( \left( 1-\frac{1}{b_n} \right) ^{b_n} \right) ^{\left( \frac{n^2}{b_n} \right)}$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left( 1-\frac{1}{b_n} \right) ^{b_n}=e^{-1}$$

$\frac{n^2}{b_n} \sim n$ for large $n$:

$a_n \sim e^{-n}$ for large $n$.

The $\sum a_n$ converges.

Comment: wuyudi.Thank you! So much nicer:)

Answer (score 2):

If $a_n$ is the $n-$th term then $\log a_n =-n^{2}\log (1+\frac n {n^{2}+1}) \leq -n^{2} \frac 1 2 (\frac n {n^{2}+1}) \leq -\frac n 4$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Comparing with $\sum e^{-n/4}$ we see that see that the series converges.

Answer (score 2):

$$0\leq \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{n}{n^2+1}\right)^{n^2}}\leq\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}\right)^n}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{\left(2-\frac{1}{n^2+1}\right)^n}\leq\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(3/2)^n}=2.$$